# SBT + ScalaTest: Custom Dependencies For Test

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

I want to test different branches within one SBT-powered projects, e.g. Feature1Spec depends on mylib_feature1.jar, Feature2Spec depends on mylib_feature2.jar and so on. How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependencies are for a project as a whole. There are two options:

1. Just have all the dependencies together. This is the simplest and should work for most cases.
2. It's very easy to create [subprojects](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html) in SBT. Put `Feature1Spec`, `Feature2Spec`, etc. in different subprojects which depend on both the main project and the extra dependencies you want.